# Php and sql trying to figure out if username exists

Tags: php, sql

This coding asks the user to input their staff ID then the database is searched and their purchase information is displayed in a table (orderID, shippingDate etc.). I want to be able to create and IF statement (quite sure its and IF statement) that makes sure that the staff ID entered exists in the database and if it does continues to the below code otherwise it displays no table just writing saying the the staff id does not exist. The html file is not included as it is not needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Prac 2 Task 3</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$staffid = $_GET["staffID"];

if($staffid != $_GET["staffID"]){
echo "Id doesnt Exist";
}
else{
true;
}
?>




<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "twa291", "twa291up");
mysql_select_db("factory291", $conn)
or die ('Database not found ' . mysql_error() );

$sql = "SELECT orderID, orderDate, orderDate, shippingDate, staffName FROM purchase, 
staff 
WHERE 
purchase.staffID = staff.staffID AND staff.staffID= '$staffid' ORDER BY purchase.orderDate ASC";

$rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn)
or die ('Problem with query' . mysql_error());



?>


<table border="1" summary="Staff Orders">
<tr>
<th>Order ID</th>
<th>Order Date</th>
<th>Shipping Date</th>
<th>Staff Name</th>
</tr>

<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) { ?>

<tr>

<td><?php echo $row["orderID"]?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["orderDate"]?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["shippingDate"]?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["staffName"]?></td>

</tr>


<?php   }
mysql_close($conn); ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: please avoid using mysql instead use mysqli or pdo because mysql will be deprecated soon

Comment: Check the size of your result set upon executing that query. If the ID doesn't exist, it will be empty. Also, you should escape your user input before executing any SQL query, to protect yourself from SQL injection attacks and other nasty things...

Comment: @www.sblog.in I'm afraid, Mysql is already deprecated as of PHP 5.5. I think you were about to say that, mysql extension for php will be removed soon

Comment: I am learning msql at uni I cannot change to msqli

Answer (score 0):

query first before showing the html

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "twa291", "twa291up");
mysql_select_db("factory291", $conn)
or die ('Database not found ' . mysql_error() );

$sql = "SELECT orderID FROM purchase WHERE 
purchase.staffID = " . $_GET["staffID"];;

$rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn)
or die ('Problem with query' . mysql_error()); 




if($rs != null ){
 //show table
}
else{
  echo "Id doesnt Exist";
}
?>
```

just fix the code , the logic is like this

Comment: your $sql statement doesn't correspond to mine. the $_GET["staffID"] is already claimed in the variable $staffid above the code you gave me (as shown in my code at the top). I tried integrating it into mine and it does not work. The  table is shown for the correct staff id with all details, but when i enter an incorrect one the table is STILL shown just with the column names only.

Comment: you need to recontruct your program , $_GET["staffID"]; can be call multiple times, the main logic is first query the id in your database with the $_GET["staffID"]; , if it doesnt exist, dont show the table